# Need some advice with this while loop

Tags: c++, while-loop

I'm having difficulties understanding the problem here.  From my perspective it looks like the loop should continue executing when any of these conditions are true.  When all of the "if" conditions are true, that should kick in and terminate the program.  What am I doing wrong?

```
double height ;
double width ;
double load ;
double buckle_threshold ;
double area ;
double compress_threshold ;
double slenderness_value ;
const int slenderness_limit = 50 ;
const int E = 1700000 ;
const int stress = 1450 ;
const int inches = 12 ;

cout << "Enter column height in feet: " ;
cin >> height ;
cout << "Enter expected load in pounds: " ;
cin >> load ;

while ( load > buckle_threshold || load > compress_threshold || slenderness_value > slenderness_limit );
{
    cout << "Enter column width in inches: " ;
    cin >> width ;

    slenderness_value = (height/width)*(inches) ;
    area = width*width ;
    buckle_threshold = (.3*E*area)/(pow((height/width),2)) ;
    compress_threshold = area*stress ;


    if (load <= buckle_threshold && load <= compress_threshold && slenderness_value <= slenderness_limit );
    {
        cout << "Compress Threshold = " << compress_threshold << endl ;
        cout << "Buckle Threshold = " << buckle_threshold << endl ;
        cout << "Column is safe." ;

        return 0;
    }

    cout << "Compress Threshold = " << compress_threshold << endl ;
    cout << "Buckle Threshold = " <<buckle_threshold << endl ;
    cout << "Column is unsafe." << endl ;

}

return 0;
```

Comment: What doesn't work? Please read [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). From a brief look, seems like you don't initialize a bunch of your variables, then use them in the condition. Maybe you want a `do while` loop.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.  Further reading: **[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a semicolon on the while/if loop.  Remove it:

```
while ( load > buckle_threshold || load > compress_threshold 
 || slenderness_value > slenderness_limit );  <--- Right there!


if (load <= buckle_threshold && load <= compress_threshold 
&& slenderness_value <= slenderness_limit );  <--- Here too!
```

Comment: @Jason Even if this makes your program work, you still have undefined behaviour from using uninitialized variables. You should address this now before it causes a weird error when you least expect it.